# Detect collision direction in Phaser3

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a 'Bomber-man' like game using Phaser3 library.
For this purpose I'd like to define a collision relationship between the **player** and the **bricks**,
and more importantly - **detect the collision direction relative the the player**.

I've noticed body properties like **touching** or **blocked** but they are always set to false. (please see below)

```js
//scene.js

// bricks static group
this.scene.physics.add.staticGroup({ immovable: true });

// player defined in external file (as sprite)
this.player = new Player(this, 90, 90)
```

```js
// player.js

// ... 

this.physics.add.collider(
  this, 
  scene.bricks,
  function(player, brick) {
  
    if(player.body.touching.left) { //ALWAYS FALSE!!!
        this.isBlockedFromLeft = true;
    }, else if(player.body.touching.right) {
        this.isBlockedFromRight = true; // ALWAYS FALSE!!!
    }
  },
  null,
  this
);
```

I'd appreciate any help. This is driving me crazy. Maybe there is a better way to do it and i'm missing something...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, if it is related but you have a typo here: `else if(player.body.touching.rigt)`. It should be `else if(player.body.touching.right)`. Do you have a link to a repo or an online code playground? I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Typo indeed. Post has been edited. Appreciate your willingness to help Manuel! You can find the git repo here: https://github.com/tamir-nakar/bomber_man . as you run it, you'll notice that it's hard to move. Knowing the collide direction will help me fix it, but maybe there is a native way of doing so ( instead of inventing the wheel). Any kind of help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May be you could get more help by posting your question in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TamirNakar is your repo outdated? I have tried to find the `player.js` file & I can't find it!

Comment: You'll find it under 'entities' dir

Comment: @TamirNakar it will be too hard for me to help because you're using classes & you're separating the scenes & files, etc... I could give you tips about my finding playing with the code.

1 - Your `player` is `undefined` from `player.js` file. 

2 - I was able to `console.log(this.player);` in the `Scene2.js` file within the `update()` method.

I think you'll need to find a way to `import` the `bricks` file there & add the collider there

Comment: Thanks for replying. Both the player and bricks are accessible from scene2. The collider is defined in player.js and seem to work since the 'block' function does invoked when collide occures. Thanks for the time you spent looking into the code. Its very appreciated.

Comment: Finally figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.

The major issue was the way I defined the player movement. It should be

```
  if (this.keyboard.right.isDown) {
    this.body.setVelocityX(this.speed);
  }
```

rather than

```
  if (this.keyboard.right.isDown) {
    this.x += this.speed;
  }
```

The second way prevent collision detection and the **body.touching** and **body.blocked** properties to be updated.

Furthermore, I've found out that when it comes to top-down tiled games, it's really easier to build up the game using the **tile-map** feature.
official examples can be found here:
https://phaser.io/examples/v3/search?search=map
and here is a tutorial of how to make a tiled-map using a light-weight software called 'Tiled'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_x1dOvgF1E

Thank you all!

Comment: Just to clarify: When using the top way, you don't have to mess with body properties at all.